# Automatically setting up a data connection on boot using qmicli and udhcpc (on linux: Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, kernel, vpn, dhcp, internet

I am currently working on a project with a raspberry pi and a 4G hat (using SIM7600E-H). I managed to setup a connection (with APN) manually and then get a lease for an IP. ([using this tutorial](https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/wireless/tutorials/sim7600)).

However, everytime I reboot my system the IP adress falls back to an IP adress with 169.xxx.xxx.xxx (it has to setup a connection again and lease the IP using udhcpc). The connection uses a raw-ip protocol, which I setup using:

```
echo 'Y' | sudo tee /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
```

I read some online articles which say that on startup, this file is used by a kernel, and can therefore not be set at startup. However, I would very much like my connection be set up autmatically on startup, and not having to do manual steps to connect everytime I reboot.

**What would be the best way to achieve this?**

Specs:

- Linux 5.4.75-v7+ #1367 SMP Mon Nov 9 15:03:59 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
- SIM7600E-H
- Raspberry Pi 3b+

Answer (score 0):

This is a few months old, but your link helped me.  Maybe this is still of value to you.

`169.254.0.0/16` is used when a machine does not have an IP address.
This is normal.
dhclient needs to run no the interface to retrieve a lease for an IP address.

You still need to enable the dhclient service for this to happen automatically.

You can look that up for whatever OS you are running.

Raspbian - Run manually with dhclient eth0 and check the services for dhcpcd and enable the service via:

```
sudo service --status-all 

sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd

sudo systemctl start dhcpcd
```